# Misplaced origin on rotateY transition

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-transitions, css-animations

I would like to keep the left edge of div.box in the same place during a transformY(-180deg) animation. I can't understand why is it moving. This is the code:

```
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
```

And here is the live example http://dabblet.com/gist/5551520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're also transitioning the transform-origin, as you use transition: all, and it is specified in the hover state. The initial value is to be centred.

If you put `transform-origin: 0% 0%;` on `.box` it will work as expected.

```
.box {
    /* removed additional styles */
    transition: all 600ms linear;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

body:hover .box {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/5551730

Comment: Oh god, finally. That's it. t was driving me crazy. Thank you very much :)